# foreach smarty template engine

Tags: smarty

I have this code:

```
{foreach $mediaArray as $media}
{if $media.dsp_type == 'photo'}
<div id="hamzawy"> {include file='contributor.media.container.tpl'} </div>
{/if}
{/foreach}
```

`$media` is equal 5 so this foreach loop 5 times to show `contributor.media.container.tpl` this `$media` variable depend on paging function so I can show any `$media` that i want (10,20,50 ... what ever) then `$media.dsp.type` hold two values (photos, videos) now I need to specify only photos to show them but when I do this it's show 4 photos only I know this is happened because I put if condition inside foreach loop. But how can I do this without if condition inside foreach loop any idea to show 5 photo per page not 4

Comment: The content of `$mediaArray` is usually determined outside of the template, in the .php file. You should add the relevant parts of that file to the question.

Comment: $mediaArray = $media->getMediaArray(); // Get the array of media

Comment: $smarty->assign('mediaArray',$mediaArray);

Comment: Simplest idea is to have different media arrays for photos and videos.

Comment: Is there is any idea else? i don't won't to create different media array for videos and photos. I have only one media array for videos and photos